# why doesnt is_home() work in functions.php

Tags: functions, hooks

I'm pulling in scripts.php through functions.php. this is in scripts.php but for some reason, wordpress isn't recognizing is_home(). i've tried resetting the query, but to no avail. Am I hooking into the right function?

```
if(is_home()){

function my_scripts_method2() {
    wp_register_script('cycle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cycle.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('cycle');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method2');

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script('homepage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/homepage.js', 'cycle');
    wp_enqueue_script('homepage');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time *functions.php* is included during bootup, WordPress has no idea on the contents of the query, and doesn't know the nature of the page. `is_home` will return false.

Wrap the code in a function and have it triggered by the `wp` hook, which comes after the global query object has been hydrated with data.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse47305_check_home' );
function wpse47305_check_home() {
    if ( is_home() )
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
}

function my_scripts() {
    ...
}
```

The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action runs after `wp`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

Answer (score -2):

try with `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` . 
It works for me ;) In my case I have this script for charging the enqueue scripts only on the front:

```
if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]=='/'){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '***********');
}
```

echo the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and you'll see his value for each page you are so you can work with it ;)

Comment: So you assume that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will always equal `/` on `is_home()`? Aside from missing quotes around that array key, you will have problems running this on the command line and maybe with cron jobs. Also a server could be set up completely different, or you could define `/home` as your home directory without stripping it. In short: This will not work.